# How can I get an id of an object that is not saved in db yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have a method in my `Cart` model:

```
def add_product_with_variant(product_id, variant_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.amount += 1
    line_item_variant = LineItemVariant.new(variant_id: variant_id, line_item_id: current_item.id)
    line_item_variant.save
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    line_item_variant = LineItemVariant.new(variant_id: variant_id, line_item_id: current_item.id)
    line_item_variant.save!
  end
end
```

In the `else` statement I use `LineItemvariant.new(variant_id: variant_id, line_item_id: current_item.id)` to assign a `variant` to a `line_item`. But in this case, I can't save `LineItemVariant`, because the `line_item` does not exist yet, and I can't use this part of code: `line_item_id: current_item.id`. Is there any solution to get the id, or there is some easier option to solve this issue? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Create the `current_item` instead of `build` and then use its `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Inside your `LineItemVariant` model define

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_item # or whatever relation is towards this item
```

And then change your else statement

Try to convert object to json when passing it use [to_json](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

```
def add_product_with_variant(product_id, variant_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.amount += 1
    line_item_variant = LineItemVariant.new(variant_id: variant_id, line_item_id: current_item.id)
    line_item_variant.save
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    line_item_variant = LineItemVariant.new(variant_id: variant_id, line_item: current_item.to_json)
    line_item_variant.save!
end
```

Comment: It gives an error: `Validation failed: Line item must exist`

Comment: Try with passing object as json

Comment: The `id` of a new `line_item` is still `nil`